# Jersey resource that matches any path

Tags: java, servlets, guice, jersey-1.0

I am using [Jersey v1.x](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/index.html) and a [Guice Servlet](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule).
What I'm trying to do is bind a Jersey Resource that matches *any* `@Path`, such that I can use Jersey to respond with a 404.

I'm looking to do this, since my servlet consists of different components (e.g. a rest API that lives under `/api`, and a web UI that lives under `/`.
In Guice terms, that means I have several `ServletModule`s that each set up one part of the servlet:

- In my `ApiServletModule`: `serve("/api").with(GuiceContainer.class, conf)`
- In my `WebUiServletModule`: `serve("/").with(GuiceContainer.class, conf)`

In this setup, I want to define what the 404 response body looks like for each part of the webapp (`/api` or `/`) from the codebase of each subproject responsible, without having to reimplement Jersey

---

So far I have tried to bind a resource that match `@Path("/")`, `@Path("*")` and `@Path("/*")`, but none of these seem to be picked up when I request `/some/path/that/doesnt/exist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30834819/1296709) is indeed correct, in the sense that it describes how you can create a Jersey resource that matches any path.
However, my goal of creating a resource that delivers 404 responses for whenever any other unmatched path is requested is not quite met by this answer:

At least in combination with Guice, will such a "match all"-resource intercept all requests, regardless of whether any more specific resources are available. Additionally, you cannot modify the HTTP response status code from within a resource.

For this purpose, Jersey has `ExceptionMapper`s that can be implemented and loaded by adding the `@Provider` annotation. One particular type would be a `ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException>`, which is invoked when a Resource throws a `NotFoundException`. The `ExceptionMapper` can then decide what response to generate, including the status code.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use the regex format of the path expression, i.e.

```
@Path("{any: .*}")
```

You could inject `List<PathSegment>` to look at all the segments if you need them.

```
public Response getSomething(@PathParam("any") List<PathSegment> segments)
```