# Grizzly JAX-RS NOT returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, rest, maven, jax-rs, grizzly

I am developing a REST API with JAX-RS. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/apaas/basic_grizzly_jersey/jersey-grizzly-json-service.html) , and now I'm running the app fine. But I have a problem with URL Paths. Grizzly automatically created the `BASE_URI` in the main method, where I addded my own path like this:

```
// Base URI the Grizzly HTTP server will listen on
public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/app/api/1.0
```

If the user enters the BASE_URI wrong e.g. `"http://localhost:8080/ap/ap/1.0/path/to/myResourse/123"` Grizzly returns

```
Not Found
Resource identified by path '/app/api/1.0/whatever/the/user/entered, does not exist.
Grizzly 2.3.28.
```

**The problem** is that if the user enters the `BASE_URI` correct, but enters my resource path wrong, Grizzly doesn't display that "Resource not found" message, but just displays a blank screen with a HTTP header of 404.

**So how can I display a `400 Bad Request`, that tells the user that he made a request to an invalid URL? And how can I change the default error message that Grizzly provides?**

I've tried searching for creating custom error messages, including ExceptionMappers, but I think that is not what I am searching. One solution I can think of, is creating a new class for each `/` in the URL Path, but that isn't a very elegant approach...?

Below is my Resource class that connects to another REST API from where it fetches resources, which I then display in my API

```
@Path("/path/to/myResourse")
public class ResourceService {

  @GET
  @Path("{id}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8")
  public Response getBuildingSite(@PathParam("id") String id) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("https://www.exmaple.com/rest/api/resources");
    sb.append(id);
    sb.append(".xml");
    String url = sb.toString();

    try {
      Resource resource = Connector.fetch(Resource.class, url);
      return JSONMapper.asOkJsonResponse(resource);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return JSONMapper.asErrorJsonResponse(
        new ErrorResponse(404,"Resource '" + id + "' not found"));
    }
  }
}
```

My pom.xml file

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.app.exampleApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>exampleApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>exampleApp</name>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.9</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.app.exampleApp.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <jersey.version>2.25</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem myself. I figured out that I can use a resource annotated by a path with a regex that matches all strings. I tested it and found out that grizzly makes a match to it only if no other 'working' resource was found.

Thanks to [peeskillet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30834819/6527865) on [derabbink's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30834696/6527865) where I found the idea.

Below is the resource I created:

```
@Path("{any: .*}")
public class NotFoundService {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
  public Response getNotFound(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    // My custom response where I can use uriInfo to tell what went wrong
  }
}
```

So now if the user enters a path that has the correct BASE URI, but an invalid resource path e.g. `"http://localhost:8080/app/api/1.0"/invalid/path` it will return whatever I put in my custom `Response`.